# cblas on centos6 cannot be linked

Tags: cblas

Here is my ldconfig

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep blas
libptf77blas.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/atlas/libptf77blas.so.3
libptcblas.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/atlas/libptcblas.so.3
libf77blas.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/atlas/libf77blas.so.3
libcblas.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/atlas/libcblas.so.3
libblas.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3
libblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libblas.so
```

When I try to compile with cblas, here is the error:

```
gcc -std=c99 -g -Wall -O0 -I../include -L../bin -I../externals/CXSparse/Include    example_als_mcmc.c  -lfastfm -L../externals/CXSparse/Lib -lcxsparse -lblas -lm -lcblas -o example_als_mcmc
```

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [example_als_mcmc] Error 1

I have cblas in ldconfig, why make cannot find it?
Thank you for your help.